# Transitive dependency classifieds android

Tags: android, dependencies

I've an android AAR (*foo*) which uses external libraries (eg. compile group: 'org.mapsforge', name: 'mapsforge-core', version: '0.6.0'). When I import it as module and try to use its classes, I get some error at Runtime about

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)'
>   on a null object reference

It seems like the app doesn't see the transitive dependencies. Does anybody know anithing about this situation? How can I import these dependencies?

Thanks in advance.